# Suddenly I'm getting "Hazelcast instance is not active!"

Tags: java, hazelcast

My application is running for months and working very well. Then suddenly I get the following error:

```
com.hazelcast.core.HazelcastInstanceNotActiveException: Hazelcast instance is not active!
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.ProxyServiceImpl$ProxyRegistry.<init>(ProxyServiceImpl.java:220)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.ProxyServiceImpl$ProxyRegistry.<init>(ProxyServiceImpl.java:207)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.ProxyServiceImpl$1.createNew(ProxyServiceImpl.java:69)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.ProxyServiceImpl$1.createNew(ProxyServiceImpl.java:67)
    at com.hazelcast.util.ConcurrencyUtil.getOrPutIfAbsent(ConcurrencyUtil.java:47)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.ProxyServiceImpl.getDistributedObject(ProxyServiceImpl.java:101)
    at com.hazelcast.instance.HazelcastInstanceImpl.getDistributedObject(HazelcastInstanceImpl.java:285)
    at com.hazelcast.instance.HazelcastInstanceImpl.getLock(HazelcastInstanceImpl.java:183)
    at com.hazelcast.instance.HazelcastInstanceProxy.getLock(HazelcastInstanceProxy.java:77)
    at br.com.xyz.lock.hazelcast.HazelcastLockManager.lock(HazelcastLockManager.java:37)
    at br.com.xyz.lock.hazelcast.LockManagerFacade.lock(LockManagerFacade.java:24)
    at br.com.xyz.recebe.negocio.NProcessadorMensagemRecebida.processamentoLock(NProcessadorMensagemRecebida.java:85)
    at br.com.xyz.recebe.negocio.NProcessadorMensagemRecebida.processaArquivo(NProcessadorMensagemRecebida.java:74)
    at br.com.xyz.recebe.processador.ProcessadorBase.processaArquivo(ProcessadorBase.java:75)
    at br.com.xyz.recebe.processador.ProcessadorXml.processaArquivo(ProcessadorXml.java:16)
    at br.com.xyz.recebe.processador.ProcessadorFacade.processaArquivo(ProcessadorFacade.java:34)
    at br.com.xyz.recebe.mail.pdes.ProcessadorPDESMeRecebida.processar(ProcessadorPDESMeRecebida.java:77)
    at gov.sefaz.util.pdes.ProcessadorDiretorioEntradaSaidaDaemon.processar(ProcessadorDiretorioEntradaSaidaDaemon.java:575)
    at gov.sefaz.util.pdes.ProcessadorDiretorioEntradaSaidaDaemon.varrerDiretorioUsingStrategy(ProcessadorDiretorioEntradaSaidaDaemon.java:526)
    at gov.sefaz.util.pdes.ProcessadorDiretorioEntradaSaidaDaemon.run(ProcessadorDiretorioEntradaSaidaDaemon.java:458)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I found some issues on Google that says it shutdown because other errors. But in my case there isn't any.

It shutdown without reason.

Has anyone seen this before?

Comment: Are you sure that Hazelcast-server is running?

Comment: Write test program with new client and try to connect to your Hazelcast node. Check it.

Comment: If test will be ok, then problem maybe in your Hazelcast client... maybe it was shutdown with OutOfMemory or some other problems.

Comment: It working for a long time. The instance was up and the node is running. But I dont get why it shutdown. I get others errors in my log, but nothing unusual.

Comment: Maybe this link will be useful: http://grepcode.com/search/usages?id=repo1.maven.org$maven2@com.hazelcast$hazelcast-all@3.0-RC2@com$hazelcast$core@HazelcastInstanceNotActiveException&type=type&k=u

Comment: @DmitryTsechoev but how I recover from that error? How I can check if the node is shutted down?

Comment: I assumed that in the source code, you can track the location where the exception is thrown. And on this basis, you can gradually try to understand the reason. Rather, the problem on the client side. You will not believe, but just got a message from the head of the exact same error in our production area! )

Comment: Not so long ago we investigated a similar problem, and if I'm not mistaken, the reason could be a short outage is Hazelcast node, after which the client falls here with this error. Run locally Hazelcast node, connect by client, turn off Hazelcast node and look at the log of the client.

Comment: @DmitryTsechoev I'm not using hazelcast-client. I just do lock and unlock in a value for synchronization: hazelcastInstance.getLock(value).lock(); and hazelcastInstance.getLock(value).unlock();

Comment: Then I can not help. Sorry.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem occurs if a hazelcast member doesn't shutdown normally (terminate), When you stop HazelcastInstance which queue proxy is bound to; then any operation on that queue after instance stopped should throw  HazelcastInstanceNotActiveException.

Comment: But I dont get why it shutdown that way. I'm sure is not OutOfMemory because my logs dont shown.

Comment: I currently using the version 3.1.5. I think it was solved after version 3. Do you know how to recover from that error?

Comment: You are right! This happened only when application is finishing. Thats not a problem so far.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to wait for a few minutes and rerun your job.